# Sharepoint workflow email being reformatted

Tags: workflow, css, email, html

I have created a workflow which sends out an email containing this html: https://jsfiddle.net/e7Lpkme2/

However, upon opening it in outlook it appears jumbled with extra white spaces and misaligned like so

[image]

Is this a problem with my html, outlook, or the workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS styles are not properly coded to make the fonts in the correct place. You have only added styles for Image not for the lists on the right side. it would be better if you create a table and add the images in one column and the text on the next column. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just converted it to tables and it is working :)